# newtonsoft json serializer removes 'ID' and adds $id for no reason

Tags: .net, serialization

A row entity with column `ID` with value `435345` serialied to json string and it cointains no ID but '$id' and value is `1`

how can I fix it?(.net framework 4.6.1)

```
var jsonString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item, new JsonSerializerSettings {
                ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize,
                PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.None,
                TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.All
            });
```

Comment: Can you post a [mcve]?